Intervals over which general solutions are defined.
I'm having trouble understanding two definitions for Linear ODE's. If I say that the general solution to a Homogeneous or Non Homogeneous Linear ODE is given over some open interval I, does this contemplate all the intervals over which such a general solution would be plausible without the initial conditions? Because, say my ODE is not defined at X=0, then is the
definition
still valid even though I now have 2 open intervals?
I have the same problem for the
Non Homogeneous case (second order in this case)
And in general for PDE's I also have this issue for the region over which we define the general solution.
Does one have to alter the definition in those cases to say "over a number of intervals/regions", or is it fine to use them as they are?

The definition as given says that a solution exists on an open interval $I$, but it does so without prejudice - by which I mean it does not prevent the solution from existing in some other domain.
The main reason why we only focus on one interval is because there does not need to be any consistency between solutions of an ODE across singularities. As a simple example, the ODE
$$x y' = 1$$
on the interval $x \in (0, \infty)$ has the general solution $y = \ln x + C$, and on the interval $x \in (-\infty, 0)$ has the general solution $y = \ln (-x) + C$, but its overall general solution is not $y = \ln |x| + C$. Instead, you can take any choice of solutions on each side of $0$ and join them together. For example, the following is a valid solution to the ODE:
$$y = \begin{cases} \ln x & x > 0 \\ \ln(-x) + 2 & x < 0 \end{cases}$$
Because of this, most theorems that talk about solutions to differential equations do so only on single intervals, or equivalents in higher dimensions (typically something like an open connected region).

I really appreciate the answer, I forgot to provide my thanks, it really helped.
